# Multi-class logistic regression Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression, tensorflow2.0

I am currently learning about multi-class classification using logistic regression in Tensoflow 2.0. I think I have built the model correctly, but during training I am constantly getting 0.333 loss and accuracy of 66.67% for every epoch. I believe the loss should be reduced, while accuracy increases for every epoch but it remains the same no matter what.

Can someone tell me what is on with my model? And why it is not converging?

```
def logisticRegression2(x,weight,bias):
    lr = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,weight),bias)
    #return sigmoid fun
    #return tf.nn.signmoid(lr)
    return lr

def crossEntropy2(yTrue,yPredicted):
    loss = tf.nn.softmax(yPredicted)
    # reduce_mean: Computes the mean of elements across dimensions of a tensor.
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

def getAccuracy2(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int64)
    preds = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=0), dtype=tf.int64)
    preds = tf.equal(y_true, preds)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(preds, dtype=tf.float64))


def gradientDescent2(x,y,weight,bias):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        yPredicted = logisticRegression2(x,weight,bias)
        lossValue = crossEntropy2(y,yPredicted)
        return tape.gradient(lossValue, [weight,bias] )

learningRate = 0.01
batchSize = 128
n_batches = 10000
optimizer2 = tf.optimizers.SGD(learningRate)


dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trX, trY))
dataset2 = dataset2.repeat().shuffle(xTrain.shape[0]).batch(batchSize)

weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,3], dtype = tf.float64))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3], dtype = tf.float64))
```

Here is my training loop:

```
predicted = []
for i, (xx2,xy2) in enumerate(dataset2.take(10000), 1):
    gradient = gradientDescent2(xx2,xy2,weight,bias)
    optimizer2.apply_gradients(zip(gradient,[weight,bias]))

    yPredicted = logisticRegression2(xx2,weight,bias)
    loss = crossEntropy2(xy2,yPredicted)
    accuracy = getAccuracy2(xy2,yPredicted)
    print("Batch number: %i, loss: %f, accuracy: %f" % (i, loss, accuracy*100))
```

Output:

```
Batch number: 1, loss: 0.333333, accuracy: 66.666667
Batch number: 2, loss: 0.333333, accuracy: 66.666667
Batch number: 3, loss: 0.333333, accuracy: 66.666667

Batch number: 9998, loss: 0.333333, accuracy: 66.666667
Batch number: 9999, loss: 0.333333, accuracy: 66.666667
Batch number: 10000, loss: 0.333333, accuracy: 66.666667
```

Comment: I am using the Iris dataset from UCI

Comment: Clearly, the implementation of cross entropy in your code is not complete/correct. You are just applying softmax on predicted values, and don't consider true labels at all!

Comment: @today ok, do you recommend something like softmax_cross_entropy, or sigmoid_cross_entropy?

Comment: Since you are doing multi-class classification you need to use [`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). Note that this function applies softmax itself, so you should not apply softmax on logits beforehand. Further the true labels should be one-hot encoded.

Comment: @today I tried softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits with the yPredicted and one-hot encoded yTrue labels , got 0% accuracy consistently

Comment: @today I get 97% acc when I comment out ```optimizer2.apply_gradients``` any idea why the optimizer is causing this?

Comment: That's strange! If you comment that line, it means the optimizer would not be active, therefore no changes would be applied on the weights of the model, hence no training!!

Comment: Oh, I got! There is a mistake in the function for computation of accuracy: use `argmax` for both predictions and true labels; and also it should be on the last axis, i.e. `axis=-1`, and NOT on the first axis, i.e. `axis=0`.

Comment: @today I updated to reflect the last axis axis= -1 for both pred and true labels, the accuracy is 100% for every batch during training, with loss = 0 and accuracy = 100 for test, does this seem right? The 0 loss for the test data is a red flag for me

Comment: That's suspicious! Is the loss 0 from the first epoch?

Comment: I'm starting to think the Iris dataset may not be the best example for this simple type of logistic regression. This is because there are 3 species in this data set, 2 of which are not linearly separable. Maybe my model is too simple and cannot fit the non-linear data.

Comment: Have you looked into the canned estimators?